# Count values in range of columns if appear in array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a large spreadsheet of values, and I want to count the number of appearances of values from an array of possibilities.

Assume we want to get all the appearances of the values in `opt1`, `opt2`,... `opt n` in the values in the range A:X.
Ihave tried using `MATCH` and `SUM`:
`=SUM(MATCH(A:X, {opt1, opt2,..., opt n}))`

However I don't get a value from it.

I have tried using `AGGREGATE` with `MATCH` and `ISNUMBER` this way:
`=AGGRAGATE(9, 4, ISNUMBER(MATCH(A:X, {opt1, opt2,..., opt n}, 0)))`

Where 9 is sum, 4 is ignore nothing.
I don't want to add another column, just use a simple countif values in the options specified.
I guess I misunderstood the shape of the results here, help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean something like `=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A2:X11;Z2:Z11))`?

Answer (score 0):

Try-

```
=SUM(--ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1:C4,{"a","e","i"},0)))
```

[image]

Comment: The old-timer `=COUNT(...)` is short for the 'modern' `=SUM(--ISNUMBER(...))`. Not that I haven't done the same on an occasion or two.